# Rounding and trimming digits with specified precision

Tags: python

Say I have a function that takes a `float` and returns a conversion to string with a pre-defined precision of `2` digits:

```
def round_and_trim(x):
    return "{0:.2f}".format(round(x,2))
```

It works as follows:

```
x = 0.238498
y = round_and_trim(x)
y = "0.24"
```

How can I make this function take an argument called `precision` so that, instead of converting to a hard-coded precision value of 2, it uses the value in `precision`?

For example

```
x = 0.238498
y = round_and_trim(x, precision=4)
y = "0.2385"
```

or:

```
x = 0.238498
y = round_and_trim(x, precision=3)
y = "0.238"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can nest replacement fields, for example:

```
def round_and_trim(x, precision=2):
    return "{0:.{prec}f}".format(round(x, precision), prec=precision)
```

So when `precision` is `3` the format string will essentially become `"{0:.3f}"`.

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> A *format_spec* field can also include nested replacement fields within it. These nested replacement fields can contain only a field name; conversion flags and format specifications are not allowed. The replacement fields within the *format_spec* are substituted before the *format_spec* string is interpreted. This allows the formatting of a value to be dynamically specified.

Comment: Interesting. How does Python know when something inside `{}` is meant to be replaced? and when it isn't? What are the rules for it?

Comment: Added some additional info.

Comment: Just for consistency with the OP's code, the `round` does seem unnecessary but I don't see how it could lead to precision problems (other than a different number of digits being used for `round` vs the format specifier).